# keras not using gpu but tensorflow is

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu, cpu

Keras is not using the my GPU, even though tensorflow seems to run fine with it. I followed other folks suggestion to check tensorflow with:

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

Which gives

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 13541243483275802230
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 6694395576
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 17715053295272939021
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:08:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"
]
```

So far so good, but when I specify a classifier in Keras and train it, it runs at glacial pace. No sign of GPU acceleration:

```
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100, verbose=1)
```

I tried this:

```
with tensorflow.device('/gpu:0'):
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
```

With the same result. 
I don't know how to tell if Keras is using GPU except by speed and obvious CPU usage.

I also ran this example from the tensorflow documentation and in my terminal I can clearly see that it uses the GPU. It runs much quicker than the keras example above.
    import tensorflow
    # Creates a graph.
    a = tensorflow.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
    b = tensorflow.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
    c = tensorflow.matmul(a, b)
    # Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
    sess = tensorflow.Session(config=tensorflow.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
    # Runs the op.
    print(sess.run(c))

I would greatly appreciate your kind help in finding out why Keras can't see my GPU

I use python 3.6.5, tensorflow-gpu 1.11.0 (tensorflow not installed), keras 2.2.4.
I need to mention that I had to fiddle a while to get tensorflow to use the GPU and I still don't know why it suddenly did, but it does so consistently now. My assumption was that Keras would automatically inherit this.

A.

Comment: I also tried this:

[`from keras import backend as K
with K.tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    config = tensorflow.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=4,\
           inter_op_parallelism_threads=4, allow_soft_placement=True,\
           device_count = {'CPU' : 1, 'GPU' : 1})
    session = tensorflow.Session(config=config)
    K.set_session(session)`]


but that didn't work to enable GPU for Keras, even though I got confirmation in my shell that the tensorflow device is active

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure anymore of my originally stated problem. I think Keras was indeed using the GPU, but that I had a significant bottleneck between CPU and GPU. When I increased the batch size, things ran significantly faster (for each epoch), which doesn't make much sense but seems to indicate I have a bottleneck elsewhere.
I have no idea how to debug this though

Comment: Yep, definitely the case.

Comment: Update: The CPU is still the bottleneck for some reason. I get a fairly decent GPU utilization (GTX1070 on an external enclosure on a laptop) considering the relatively small network size, but I was expecting less CPU and more GPU. It is definitely not optimal. Strangely my surface pro 3 (its a few years old now) with i7 runs faster than the Dell Latitude 7480 with external GPU combination.

Answer (score -1):

You could try removing your keras and install keras-gpu instead (available in anaconda, maybe in pip too)

If you want to be sure to use `with tensorflow.device('/gpu:0'):`, use it "when defining the model":

```
with tensorflow.device('/gpu:0'):

    #blablablabla - layers for functional API model

    classifier = Model(inputs, outputs) #or classifier = Sequential()

    #blablabla - layers for sequential model
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I tried installing keras-gpu, but pip cannot find it.
I had already tried the device
[`with tensorflow.device('/gpu:0'):
    config = tensorflow.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=4,\
           inter_op_parallelism_threads=4, allow_soft_placement=True,\
           device_count = {'CPU' : 1, 'GPU' : 1})
    session = tensorflow.Session(config=config)
    K.set_session(session)
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)`]
but that didn't seem to do anything